# Add and change data from asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have very little experience with asp.net and need some help with a presumably simple task.

I have a table in the database that consists of date, headline, text and a flag that says if the headline is to be displayed on the start page.

I want help to code the webform to meet the following requirements:

1. The date, title and flag must be listed in a table (BUT NOT THE TEXT).
2. You must be able to change the flag with a single click.
3. You must be able to change the headline AND TEXT for a row.
4. You must be able to add a new row.

Comment: What is your question? You say you have problems, but not what they are.

Comment: @ Oded: Sorry, I'm not so great in English. I hope I explained it better now.

Comment: You still did not explain _exactly_ what you are having problems with. The UI? The data connection? The SQL?

Comment: What aspects of the UI are you having problems with? What exactly? What did you try? What didn't work? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I get a list of all items when I use the ListView, but I want to be able to to change flag, edit text without the text shown in the list and add a new line.

Comment: @Aristos: I know how to read from a databse. I have already arranged with the data access, I just need help with the UI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can partion the page to two sections:

1- a form contains the fields (text and headline) on a panel to show and hide .the default to this panel is (visible = false).and a button to save changes.

2- a panel contains a gridview , the grid view bind on your table , but take care to use a template field to put the check box and bind the Checked property to the flag field.add a template field and add a link button to edit the row.when you clicked the link then you hide this  panel and show the above panel to edit the data.

this is an initial view to the UI.